# Cannot find type definition file for 'node'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I am getting strange errors after updating angular, webpack and typescript. 
Any idea what I could be missing?

When I run the app with npm start I get the following errors:

```
[at-loader] Cannot find type definition file for 'hammerjs'.
[at-loader] Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
[at-loader] src\app\app.component.ts:26:14
Cannot find name 'require'.
[at-loader] src\app\app.component.ts:30:15
Cannot find name 'require'.
```

Here are the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.4.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.4.4",
"@angular/core": "2.4.4",
"@angular/forms": "2.4.4",
"@angular/http": "2.4.4",
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.4",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.4.4",
"@angular/router": "3.4.4",
"@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.13",
"@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
"@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.18",
"angular2-jwt": "0.1.28",
"angular2-moment": "1.1.0",
"auth0-lock": "10.10.1",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.5",
"cky-meta": "^1.0.2",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"hammerjs": "2.0.8",
"http-server": "^0.9.0",
"ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"ng2-img-cropper": "0.7.7",
"ng2-page-scroll": "3.2.1",
"ng2-sharebuttons": "1.1.5",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
"rxjs": "5.0.3",
"web-animations-js": "2.2.2",
"zone.js": "0.7.6"
   },
      "devDependencies": {
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.4.4",
"@types/chai": "3.4.34",
"@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
"@types/es6-shim": "^0.31.32",
"@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.5.41",
"@types/node": "^6.0.60",
"@types/protractor": "^4.0.0",
"@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.39",
"@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
"@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
"@types/webpack": "^2.2.2",
"add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.2",
"angular-router-loader": "^0.5.0",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
"assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.0.0-beta.18",
"bootstrap-loader": "2.0.0-beta.19",
"codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
"css-loader": "^0.26.0",
"exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
"expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
"file-loader": "^0.9.0",
"gh-pages": "^0.12.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.26.0",
"imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
"istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "1.2.0",
"jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
"json-loader": "^0.5.4",
"karma": "^1.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.2",
"karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "2.0.1",
"ng2-facebook-sdk": "1.2.0",
"ngc-webpack": "^1.1.2",
"node-sass": "4.3.0",
"npm-run-all": "^4.0.1",
"parse5": "^3.0.1",
"postcss-loader": "1.2.2",
"protractor": "^4.0.14",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"resolve-url-loader": "1.6.1",
"rimraf": "~2.5.4",
"sass-loader": "4.1.1",
"script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.5.0",
"source-map-loader": "^0.1.6",
"string-replace-loader": "^1.0.5",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
"ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
"ts-node": "^2.0.0",
"tslint": "4.3.1",
"typedoc": "^0.5.5",
"typescript": "2.1.5",
"typings": "2.1.0",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"v8-lazy-parse-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
"webpack": "2.2.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.2.0",
"webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
"webpack-merge": "~2.4.0"
```

},
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }

Comment: I found a solution, Please refer below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/45810467/1522823

Comment: Anybody here looking for typescript 5, it's because of this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-1/#explicit-typeroots-disables-upward-walks-for-node_modules-types

Answer (score 4):

Try re-importing the @types/node package by running this in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio:

```
npm i -D @types/node
```

If a specific version must be used, you can specify:

```
npm i -D @types/node@6.0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems more likely to be a problem of versions within the `typings.json` file. Can you try the following?

```
typings install dt~node --save
typings install dt~core-js --save
typings install dt~hammerjs --save
```

Comment: I don't have typings in my package.json, but still facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could either be a mismatched ts-node version in which updating ts-node should fix it [found here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16772#issuecomment-311578985) or it could be an incorrect tsconfig.json [found here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/1411#issuecomment-299641553)

If these don't work here are some links you may find useful:

https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal/issues/213

[VS2015: "Cannot find type definition" and "File not found" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620063/vs2015-cannot-find-type-definition-and-file-not-found-errors)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after doing an npm update I was getting this error. It disappeared by restarting my node server :

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

## You might need to apply multiple solutions to solve this issue!

## STEP 1

You might need to install missing typings from @types
it's already present and still you are getting this error proceed to step 2

## STEP 2

If you are using ts-loader you will need to upgrade this

## STEP 3 (Not applicable to all)

In some cases it's the webpack versioning which causes this error; upgrading to webpack version, ts-node, awesome-typescript-loader etc will solve it for you

## STEP 4 (Angular only)

If you have used core-js upgrade its version

In general solution varies for all however its the node modules version where you will need to play around a bit! It's more of hit and try

All the best!