# Build:Cannot find type definition file for 'node'

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, angular

VS 2015 community edition (at home), npm 3.10, Angular 2
Im trying to pull get Angular2 setup within an ASP.Net MVC 5 app.  The template I started with used an older version of Angular, so I updated the package references.

When I build, the first error in the list is:
*Build:Cannot find type definition file for 'node'*

There are dozens of other errors after that but Im assuming most are due to this first issue.

Here is the package.json and typings.json

package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "aspnet",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.41",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",
    "typings": "~2.1.1"
  }
}
```

typings.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
}
```

If I try to update just the typings, I get these messages

```
*typings WARN deprecated 11/21/2016: "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)
typings WARN deprecated 9/14/2016: "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)
typings WARN deprecated 10/25/2016: "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)*
```

[ **update** ]
cleaning out my node_modules folder, then running npm install again cleared things up.  This seems to happen most often when I move a project folder to another location on my system.

Comment: Try to install the latest LTS Node.js version first, it might be an outdated Node version.

Also, I think typings are deprecated.

Comment: did you find any solution to this by any chance?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had several problems updating packages through visual studio. From now i always update or add packages with the powershell console.

Start `PowerShell` and navigate to the folder where `package.json` is located and then run `npm install` Restart visual studio after the installation is done.

You can also try to delete your `node_modules` folder then run `npm install`

Hope this will solve your problems.

Comment: I just had this problem and just running npm install fixed it

Comment: Side node, this is still true for vs2019. I tried using the package manager console to run `npm install` but that also did not work, i really had to go open cmd and run it there for it to work.

Comment: npm install with PS is wwwayyyyy slower, just a tip. Use simple command line or bash.

Comment: Restarting vscode was a necessary step for me on Windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 219):

In my case, I solved my problem. Hopefully it helps some else later.

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

Comment: should be --save-dev. How come microsoft's node project template is missing it? Don't they test their stuff?

Comment: This answer solved things for me right away,including for a nested project

Comment: Adding the same for @types/jasmine and @types/jasminedw2 also resolve similar errors for those packages. (Using TypeScript 2.0 without NuGet in Visual Studio 2019!)

Comment: @Mikser why should it be --save-dev? Doesn't this library contain only compile-time structures? I mean there might be no difference

Comment: @xotonic, It actually depends on the way your project is built and run. One might need an optimized production build without devDependencies modules that take up extra space.

Comment: Can you explain what it install exactly

Comment: @BobtheBuilder it will install the typescript definitions for the Node.js runtime as dev dependency(use --save-dev flag with npm install) and its modules.

Answer (score 38):

Restarting or reloading my VSCode worked

Comment: This seemed like a long shot, but it actually worked!

Comment: His using Visual Studio, Not VS Code.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had the problem because of the presence of the following in my tsconfig:

```
"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@type"]
```

Removing that line fixed the problem.

Comment: this worked for me in server/tsconfig.json where I already had `"types": ["node", "jasmine"]`

Comment: You should set `node_modules/@types`, not `@type`

Answer (score 6):

On my end, this was an issue with the TS server in VSCode. You can simply restart the server by:

Opening any TS file > <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> > TypeScript: Restart TS Server

Answer (score 5):

I faced exact issue while trying to upgrade to Angular 17 which needs typescript >=5.2 & < 5.3.

To fix it you need to have:

1. typeRoots in tsconfig.json
2. Specify all possible paths where node_modules/@types might be present. Post typescript 5.1 parent directory walking has been disabled. More info here - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-1/#explicit-typeroots-disables-upward-walks-for-node_modules-types

In my case below snippet in tsconfig.json fixed it:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": [ "node" ],
        "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types", "../node_modules/@types", "../../node_modules/@types" ]
}
```

If you don't have a mono repo the first value inside typeRoots might be sufficient. Do note the leading dot signifying relative path.

Comment: This one solved my issue with an Angular 17 app. I didn't even have to manually specify the '"types": [ "node" ]' to get it working. Just adding the type roots did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

sometimes its just because some package(s) are missing. you can try running `yarn install` or `npm install` should resolve.

Answer (score 3):

#### For local Visual Studio

If you're starting with a clean template the build in VS functionality should probably work!

Go to `Dependencies` > `npm` > Right Click > `Restore Packages`

Then try build again.

#### For Visual Studio Team Services

- Install node https://nodejs.org/en/download/
- Restart your agent service (VSTS Agent) if not using hosted agents
- Add a build task to run npm install
- Click the menu icon next to 'Working folder' to choose the location where your project.json file is located.

  [image: enter code here]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to go around this in vscode is.

create a .vscode directory, then inside it, create settings.json and put the below json and you are good to go.

```
{
"search.exclude": {
  "**/node_modules": true
},
"files.watcherExclude": {
  "**/.git/objects/**": true,
  "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
  "**/node_modules/**": true,
  "env-*": true
},
"files.exclude": {
  "**/.git": true,
  "**/.DS_Store": true,
  "**/node_modules": true,
  "env*": true
}
}
```

Comment: His using Visual Studio, Not VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

Restart Typescript or re-open vscode worked for me

Answer (score 1):

for rocketchat apps, this should fix the problem:

`npm link @types/node`

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be around other issues as well

Try one of the step of the solution posted here [Cannot find type definition file for 'node'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41834391/cannot-find-type-definition-file-for-node/59854173#59854173) by me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when i've been working with RN and i put a incorrect dependency on my package.

```
    "@types/": "react-navigation/native",
```

**react-navigation/native** don't exists

json[image]

When i tried run tsc with it, i got this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the package has been deprecated,
[image]
when I `npm install`, the issue starts here, I've removed that package in `package.json` and removed the node_modules folder, `npm install` again, and restarted the app, it's worked for me