# Typescript cannot recognize node

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": [
      "ES6",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ], <--- this line
    "typeRoots": [
      "@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./public/*",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Even I already do `npm install @types/node --save-dev` on the project directory, the error still shows that `Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.`. May I ask what will be the solution in order to have the types `node` be recognized in Typescript React project?

I found some solutions and expect the error should be gone but the error still does not disappear.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45810467/3717691

Comment: did you restart the TS server/compiler after installing the types? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75772063/2938073

Answer (score 0):

If the comment from Jeppe
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45810467/371769
didn't help you, then you may try these steps:

1. Explicitly Add "types" to tsconfig.json

   ```
   "types": ["node"]
   ```
2. Update npm and Clear npm Cache

   ```
   npm install -g npm@latest 

   npm cache clean --force
   ```
3. Remove your node_modules directory and reinstall project dependencies

   ```
   rm -rf node_modules
   npm install
   ```

Then you can start your project. It should work.