# VS2015: "Cannot find type definition" and "File not found" errors

Tags: visual-studio, angular, ng2-translate

I have an Angular2 app which worked perfectly fine until two days ago. When I tried to build the solution in Visual Studio 2015, I got 10 errors:

```
Build: Cannot find type definition file for 'hammerjs'.
Build: Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'.
Build: File (...)/wwwroot/lib/ng2-translate/index.ts' not found.
```

And 6 more about various files in ng2-translate not found.

Surprisingly, when I build my app by dotnet run command, it works well.
I updated everything by `npm-check-updates -u`, but it didn't change anything.
My package.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "CarMarket",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.3",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~4.0.3",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.1",
    "body-parser": "1.17.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "fancybox": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.20.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^7.0.13",
    "del": "2.2.2",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "3.1.6",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.11",
    "merge": "1.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  }
}
```

What might be the reason of those errors? H

Answer (score 2):

As the error clearly states, you are missing type definitions for hammerjs and jasmine.  You can either add them to your typings definition file, or you can install the types packages directly:

```
npm install --save @types/hammerjs
npm install --save @types/jasmine
```

Comment: I solved it already but that wasn't an issue - actually adding  `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>True</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` to .xproj made it work. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome, glad you were able to solve it on your own!